# Makefile: immedate assignment evaluated lazily?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to have *.s files as inputs, and files with the extension stripped as output files. I thought I could use an immediate binding with `($basename ...)`, but this does not work. My minimal example:

```
INPUT := *.s
OUTPUT := $(basename $(INPUT))

all:
    echo 'input:' $(INPUT)
    echo 'output:' $(OUTPUT)
```

when running, produces

```
echo 'input:' *.s
input: hello.s int3.s
echo 'output:' *
output: Makefile int3 hello hello.o hello.s int3.s
```

I thought the `:=` would force immediate evaluation, but it seems to actually do a lazy binding, and the basename strips the ".s" from the "*". Thus this will result in all files in the directory. How to I get this to just give me the .s files with the extension removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace:

```
INPUT := *.s
```

with:

```
INPUT := $(wildcard *.s)
```

The first causes immediate assignment of `*.s` to `INPUT`, which you don't
want. The second causes immediate assignment of the filename-list resulting
from expansion of [`$(wildcard *.s)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html), which you do want.

See [4.4.1 Wildcard Examples](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Examples.html)
and note:

> Wildcard expansion does not happen when you define a variable. Thus, if you write this:

```
objects = *.o
```

> then the value of the variable objects is the actual string ‘*.o’. [...]
>   To set objects to the expansion, instead use:

```
objects := $(wildcard *.o)
```

Comment: So if the `:=` does not imply 'evaluate the *', how is it different from the `=` operator?